# Best way to prevent HTML Code in Textbox MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have following code on my view.
This HTML code is used for search in website.
This view is not strongly typed view, so I can apply use `DataAnnotation` through model.
What is best view to validate that, this textbox should accept only alpha numeric characters?

HTML

```
<form action="Search" method="post" >
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="search" class="fullwidth" onkeypress="return BlockingHtml(this,event);" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" title="Search" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
function BlockingHtml(txt) {
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r.]+/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="Search" method="post" >
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="search" class="fullwidth" onblur="return BlockingHtml(this,event);" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" title="Search" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Changed event `onkeypress` to `onblur`.

Answer (score 1):

Model:-

```
[StringLength(100)]
[Display(Description = "Name")]
[RegularExpression("(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r.]+/g", ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets and numbers of Name")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

**Updated:-**

**View:-**

```
 <form action="Search" method="post" >
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="txt" placeholder="search" class="fullwidth" onkeypress="BlockingHtml(this);" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" title="Search" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </form>


function BlockingHtml(txt) {
            txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r.]+/g, '');
        }
```

Comment: I don't have Model for this view, I have mentioned it in question.

Comment: Thanks! But if I copy html from somewhere else & paste it in text box, replace is not happening.

Comment: Can you post your html

Comment: If I type <h1> in notepad, copied it & pasted into search text box. After hitting search button, 500 error is there.

Comment: Got an Idea. just changed event from keypress to onblur.

Comment: Yes, it is, because even if you copy & paste, when you will leave text box JS Function will do its work.